# How to return Arraylist from AsyncTask to UI thread

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-asynctask, android-webview

I need help with returning Arraylist of ArrayList OUT from AsyncTask or setting a webview within AsyncTask. I tried to set a webview from within AsyncTask and got an error that told me that I had to do this within a UI thread.
Then I tried to return a arralist of arraylist from AsyncTask to my UI thread which did not work that either.

This is the error I recieved:

java.lang.Throwable: Warning: A WebView method was called on thread  'AsyncTask #3'. All WebView methods must be called on the UI thread. Future  versions of WebView may not support use on other threads.

Oncreate()
---->Call my AsyncTask and then start it with task.execute
The AsyncTask itself will execute onPostExecute() when it's ready and then it will return nothing because it is void.

Code block 1

```
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.tab2);
                    ...
                    ...
                    queriesAsync task = new queriesAsync();
                    task.execute(new String[] { DatabasePath });
                    ...
```

Code block 2

```
            private class queriesAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList> {
            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... pathToDB) {
                ///Do something
                return ArrayList;
            }

            @Override
                protected void onPostExecute (ArrayList result){
                // return?
                }
            }
```

Comment: [AsyncTask javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) that explains how to use [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...))

Comment: Atleast add some code with your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet that you are not using `AsyncTask`'s `onPostExecute()`, which runs on the UI `Thread` after `doInBackground()` finishes. When `doInBackground()` finishes it returns the desired result to `onPostExecute()` which runs on the UI `Thread`. Here you can manipulate `UI` components as you please.

Comment: Hi I use that onPostExecute() but that is a viod function right?

Comment: What do you mean by "void function"?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute()
It does not like when I'm trying to change that to other then void

Comment: Yes, and what is the problem? It receives the result from `doInBackground()` and it runs on the UI `Thread`.